# What does “Verhältnis” actually mean?

Tags: meaning

What does *Verhältnis* actually mean?

> Verhältnis means ratio

I know that the verb *halten* means *to hold*.

Is there any subtle relationship between the verb *halten* and *Verhältnis* and *ratio*?

Comment: Related: Check the "Herkunft" section of [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Verhaeltnis)

Comment: You want to understand *“verhalten”* first.

Comment: As a side note: "Ein Verhältnis" can also be "an affair". ;)

Comment: It's not so easy. Almost never one word in a given language translates into only one single word in another language. Depending on context you can have dozens of different translations. Depending on context, the German verb »halten« can be translated as »carry, hold, stop, breed, last, think« and many more. There are lots of situations where it simply would be wrong to translate »halten« as »hold«. And there also are lots of situations, where it would be wrong to translate »Verhältnis« as »ratio«, because also »Verhältnis« has lots of different translations with different meanings.

Comment: *Actually* is a very poor choice, to describe, what you're looking for.

Comment: A very wild guess: It **could** also be related to "Haltung", which sometimes means something like *attitude* or *opinion*. But honestly, I never thought about this so much.

Answer (score 7):

The noun `Verhältnis` is a derivative of the verb `sich (zu etwas oder jemandem) verhalten`. (In contrast, the noun `Verhalten` is another derivative of `sich verhalten` but concerns the usage without `zu etwas oder jemandem`.)

Verb and noun express a relationship in general. In detail this can mean:

- an affair (Only in case of the noun `Verhältnis`. The corresponding verb would be `ein Verhältnis haben`.)
- a familial/professional/whatever relationship between persons
- a ratio or abstract relationship between numbers, quantities, structures, … for example the ratio of 2 numbers, 2/3, or the orthogonality of straight lines.

Comment: another question : why does not beziehung mean a ratio as verhaeltnis , vielen dank im voraus

Comment: @iye ad 1) another question, ad 2) why should it? Beziehung is "only" relationship between something (can also be between objects)

Comment: @iye: Ich sehe da keinen gr. Unterschied. Man kann an Schnüren ziehen und jmd. mit einem Seil halten. Insofern finde ich da mehr Ähnlichkeit als Unterschied. Auch: "In welcher Beziehung/in welchem Verhältnis stehen A und B zueinander?" ist sehr ähnlich.

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with the verb

### halten

this verb has this meanings:

- to prevent something from moving by using physical power in the opposite direction

  > Dieser Träger muss das gesamte Gewicht **halten**.
  >   This carrier has to **hold/carry** the whole weight.
- to keep a status unchanged

  > Ich will mein Gewicht **halten**.
  >   I want to **keep** my weight.
- to breed farm animals or pets (also used reflexive)

  > Frau Müller **hält** 20 Schafe und 15 Ziegen.
  >   Ms. Müller **breeds** 20 sheep and 15 goats.
  >
  > Herr Gruber **hält sich** einen Pudel.
  >   Mr. Gruber **has** a poodle.
- (reflexiv) to prevent something from rotting

  > Käse **hält sich** länger, wenn man ihn im Kühlschrank aufbewahrt.
  >   Cheese **lasts** longer when stored in the refrigerator.
- to make a speculation (with »für *etwas*«)

  > Ich **halte** solche Aussagen für gefährlich.
  >   I **think** such statements are dangerous.
- to stop (train, bus)

  > Der Bus **hält** hier nicht.
  >   The Bus doesn't **stop** here.

It's original meaning was: To breed cattle or other farm animals, to hold them together and to let them eat gras. (»Vieh halten«)

---

### verhalten

This can be an adjective or a verb, it is derived from »halten«.

**verb**

When used as a verb, it has this meanings:

- to hold back, to suppress (in modern German only used as participle)

  > Der Chef hat auf unseren Vorschlag sehr **verhalten** reagiert.
  >   The boss reacted very **guarded** on our proposal.
- (reflexive) to behave

  > Wenn man es abkühlt, **verhält** sich Wasser anders als andere Substanzen.
  >   When cooling down, water **behaves** different than other substances.
  >
  > Walter **verhält** sich immer so.
  >   Walter always **behaves** this way.

**adjective**

- inconspicuous, quiet, reserved

  > Lisa zeigte ein **verhaltenes** Lächeln.
  >   Lisa showed a **reserved** smile.

This verb »verhalten« obviously derives from »halten«, but in a way you might not expect. The Old High German word »firhaltan« came into German vocabulary as a translation of the latin »prōstituere« which literally means »to put into the front« but was used in the meaning of »to reveal someones body for public fornication«. But this meaning turned, and when it was used some centuries later, in Middle High German as »verhalten«, it meant »to keep closed, to keep hidden, to keep as a secret«. To understand, how this later turned into »to behave« you better read the section about the noun »Verhalten« below.

---

there are two nouns derived from the verb »verhalten«:

### das Verhalten

This noun is the nominalized infinitiv of the verb »verhalten«. First it was used only to describe an inconspicuous, quiet and reserved way to behave (like the synonyms »Benehmen, Betragen« are still used in German), but later it was used as a noun meaning »behavior« in any means.

So, today »Verhalten« means:

- what someone does (or not does), and the way how he/she does it.

  > Das **Verhalten** von Dr. Stein, als er Frau Fink sah, war unerwartet.
  >   The **behavior** of Dr. Stein, when he saw Ms. Fink, was unexpected.

### das Verhältnis

This noun describes the *Verhalten* of a person or thing regarding someone or something else. So it originally means the kind of behaviour that one shows with respect to something else.

In modern German »das Verhältnis« has this meanings:

- a ratio (i.e. measurable relationship) between two things

  > Das **Verhältnis** der Längen der beiden Diagonalen eines Quadrats ist genau 1.
  >   The **ratio** of the lengths of the both diagonals of a square is exactly 1.
- a relationship between persons

  > Das **Verhältnis** zwischen Ernst und Helga war angespannt.
  >   The **relationship** between Ernst and Helga was tense.
- an intimate relationship

  > Lisa und Markus haben ein **Verhältnis**.
  >   Lisa and Markus have an **affair**.
- general circumstances (only in plural)

  > Die politischen **Verhältnisse** in diesem Land ermöglichen keinen Wohlstand.
  >   The political **situation** in this country does not allow for prosperity.

Answer (score 0):

Verhältnisse (the plural) also be translated as "circumstances" or "conditions."  From Der Dreigroschenoper, Über die Unsicherheit menschlicher Verhältnisse:

> "Wir wären gut - anstatt so roh, Doch die Verhältnise, sie sind nicht so."

Comment: This doesn’t really answer the question on what *Verhältnis* in relation to *halten* and how it evolved from that word.

Comment: @Jan: To be fair: Neither does the other answer.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft True. Maybe I should flag it as NAA, too ;)